# Multipart file upload using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

Is there any way to upload multipart file using jQuery in JSP + java.
Getting error while doing in jQuery AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/users/imageUpload/" + $imageUpload + "/" + $userId‌​,
    contentType: "multipart/form-data",
    processData: false,
}).done(function(data) {}).fail(function(data) {
    alert("Ooopss..! Something Bad Happened.!");
});
```

Comment: Can you show, what you have tried so far?

Comment: $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/users/imageUpload/"+$imageUpload+"/"+$userId,
          contentType: "multipart/form-data",
                processData: false,
         }).done(function(data){
         
         }).fail(function(data){
          alert("Ooopss..! Something Bad Happened.!");
         });

Comment: also not getting the value in form serialize

Comment: This comment should go as update to the question. Also, share the server side code that accepts the AJAX request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("input:file").change(function(objEvent) {
    var objFormData = new FormData();
    // GET FILE OBJECT 
    var objFile = $(this)[0].files[0];
    // APPEND FILE TO POST DATA
    objFormData.append('userfile', objFile);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Here Your Server-Url'
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        data: objFormData,
        //JQUERY CONVERT THE FILES ARRAYS INTO STRINGS.SO processData:false
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {}
    });
});
```

Comment: @RequestMapping("/imageUpload/{image}/{userId}")
public String formForImageUpload(Model model, @PathVariable("image") MultipartFile image, @PathVariable("userId") Integer userId  ) {
 Users users = new Users();
 model.addAttribute("users", users);
 return null;
}

Comment: above mentioned code is am using in java controller

Comment: @Ali, Better to add some description, rather tossing up the code out there.

Comment: How i will get the FormData in controller?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("yourFormID")); // your form ID
var url = jQuery("#yourFormID").attr("action"); // your form action 
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data, // this will get all the input fields of your form.
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    dataType: 'json', // as you want
    success: function(response) {        
        // success 
    }
});  // JQUERY Native Ajax End
```